# Issue with deplying Next.js application to Vercel that uses Spline

Tags: reactjs, next.js, spline, react-three-fiber

I am creating a website where I am using spline and react-three-fiber with next.js. Now spline has a package called @splinetool/r3f-spline. Everything is working fine during development time. Also works fine when I do the next build and Next start but as soon as I try to deploy I have errors in the @splinetool/r3f-spline.
`Module not found: Can't resolve '@splinetool/loader' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@splinetool/r3f-spline/dist'`
I would be really grateful if someone can help me out here.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to explicitly add `@splinetool/loader` to the dependencies of the project? To do this run:

```
npm install @splinetool/loader
```

When developing locally the dependency might be there as a transitive dependency of any of the `devDependency` or for some other reason.